# Clisp - translating pseudocode into actual lisp code

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to define a A* search algorithm in lisp

the pseudocode can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

this is what I have so far:

```
;;; A*
(defun a* (problem)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  cameFrom -> Parent do node 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  gScore   -> node-g
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  fScore   -> node-g  +  node-h        
    (setq closedSet '())
    (setq openSet (list (make-node :state (problem-initial-state problem))))
    (setq listaVizinhos '())

    (loop while(not(eq openSet nil))  

        (setq tamanho_openS (list-length (openSet)))                                                            ;                            
        (setq current (nth 0 openSet))                                                                          ; 
        (dotimes (i tamanho_openS)                                                                              ;PARA ENCONTRAR O NODE COM MENOR FSCORE
            (if (< (+ (node-g (nth i openSet)) (node-h (nth i openSet)))  (+ (node-g current) (node-h current)))  ;                CURRENT
            (setq current (nth i openSet))))                                                                    ;

        (if (funcall (problem-fn-isGoal problem) (node-state current)) (return-from a* (solucao current)))      ; caso current seja solucao -> retorna-o para a funcao solucao (que cria a solucao pedida)

        (remove current openSet) ; retira o curretn da lista dos abertos
        (append (list(current)) closedSet) ; introduz curretn na lista dos fechados

        (setf estadosVisinhos (nextStates (node-state current))) ; nextestates de current-state
        (setf tamanho_estadosVizinhos (list-length (estadosVisinhos)))

        (dotimes (i tamanho_estadosVizinhos)                                              ;
            (setf visinho (make-node :parent current :state (nth i estadosVisinhos)))       ;PARA CRIAR LISTA COM TODOS NODES VIZINHOS DE CURRENT 
            (append (list(visinho)) listaVizinhos))                                         ;                    LISTAVIZINHOS

        (loop for vizinho in listaVizinhos do  
            (if (member vizinho closedSet) (continue))

            (setq tentative_gScore (+ (node-g current) (dist_between current vizinho)))   

            (if (not(member vizinho closedSet)) (append (list(vizinho)) openSet))          ;
            (if (>= (tentative_gScore) (node-g vizinho)) (continue))                       ; MAYBE CONDS AQUI

            (setq (node-g vizinho) tentative_gScore)
            (setq (node-f vizinho) (+ (node-g vizinho) (compute-heuristic (node-state vizinho))))
)
)

(return-from a* nil))
```

and my node structure is:

```
;;; Definition of a search node
;;;  * parent - the parent node
;;;  * state - the state of the node
;;;  * f - estimate of the cost
;;;  * g - cost from the initial node to the current node
;;;  * h - estimate of the cost from the current node to the nearest goal
(defstruct node
   parent
   state
   f
   g
   h)
```

In my translation I use other functions but those I have already tested and are correct.

When I try to compile my code I get a syntax error but i do not know where..

EDIT:
error message:

```
LOOP: illegal syntax near (setq tamanho_openS (list-length (openSet))) in loop (and then the terminal prints the entire loop)
```

Comment: 1. please fix indentation (e.g., use emacs to edit your code); 2. please paste  the error message text exactly; 3. please use `let` instead of `setq` for local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the "extended" [loop](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm) form, so you need to do

```
(loop while ...
  do ...)
```

instead of

```
(loop while ...
  ...)
```

This is what the error is telling you: it wants a keyword after `while` condition, and it found the first statement of the body.

You might want to review [The LOOP Facility](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm) more carefully.

PS. Please *bind* local variables using [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) or, in `loop`, [`with`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abb.htm), before setting them with [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm). Otherwise your variables are global specials.

PPS. Please indent your code properly; you can use Emacs for that.

Comment: yep, thanks, my guess at your error was correct, you are missing `do` before the body.